# The type or namespace name 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, namespace

Estou com um problema na hora de publicar ou compilar o projeto, aparece o seguinte erro:

> The type or namespace name 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be found in
>   the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?

Alguém sabe do que se trata? Já instalei o `ASPAJAXExtSetup` e nada.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa declarar na sua configuração:

```
<packages>
  <package id="AjaxControlToolkit" version="8.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```